# gensim installed in anaconda env but won't import in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda, gensim

I'm trying to install gensim in a specific conda env on my Python 3 only, Windows 10 machine. I've tried 3 different ways based on suggestions in SO and elsewhere, summarized below. Each time it shows as successfully installed and present in the env, but when I try to import it in jupyter notebook I get the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim'` error.

Note: I closed and relaunched anaconda and jupyter after each install.

SUMMARY: 
3 attempts with 3 install commands:

```
COMMAND                              CONDA LIST                              IMPORT IN JUPYTER NOTEBOOK
conda install -c anaconda gensim     gensim 3.4.0 py36hfa6e2cd_0 anaconda    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim'
pip install -U gensim                gensim 3.7.3 pypi_0 pypi                ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim'
conda install -c conda-forge gensim  gensim 3.7.3 py36h6538335_0 conda-forge ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim'
```

```
(base) C:\Users\kb>conda activate SARC
(SARC) C:\Users\kb>conda install -c anaconda gensim
(SARC) C:\Users\kb>conda list
. . .
gensim                    3.4.0            py36hfa6e2cd_0    anaconda
. . .

. . .
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e92e291fb8cb> in <module>
      1 import loader
      2 import reader
----> 3 import transformers
      4 import vectorization

~\OneDrive\Documents\ds\courses_books\Applied_Text_Analysis_Python_book_code\atap-master\snippets\ch04\transformers.py in <module>
      3 import os
      4 import nltk
----> 5 import gensim
      6 import unicodedata
      7 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim'
```

Details of the install commands and output can be seen [here](https://github.com/nicolas-ivanov/debug_seq2seq/issues/23#issuecomment-508880177).

Comment: maybe Jupyter uses fourth Python? How do you run Juputer ? Do you use `python -m juputer notebook` ?

Comment: I open Anaconda prompt, activate env, run jupyter notebook. See image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LjCW.jpg

Comment: What happens if you try @furas suggestion of `python -m jupyter notebook`? It's possible that the command `jupyter` is using a Python other than the one intended/needed by your `SARC` environment. (Also, it's usually better to expand your question with required info, as formatted text, than resort to screenshots.)

Comment: @gojomo, I get the following error when I activate my Anaconda env that contains gensim and then run that command: `(base) C:\Users\karls>conda activate SARC

(SARC) C:\Users\karls>python -m jupyter notebook
C:\Users\karls\Anaconda3\envs\SARC\python.exe: No module named jupyter`

Comment: Thanks! That's suggests that `jupyter` isn't installed in the `SARC` environment – and when you succeed in invoking it via plain `jupyter`, it's running some other non-SARC-environment `python`. Ensure that `jupyter` is installed inside `SARC`-env, then try that `python -m jupyter notebook` method again (which ensures the right conda-environment-respecting `python` is being used)

Comment: Thanks, @gojomo. I'm now finding other packages that aren't installed in the env and were using the version installed in the base env (which used a later version of python). Busy installing those. What exactly does the `-m` option do?

Comment: `-m` specifies a module that the `python` interpreter will look for a `__main__` function inside. So it's a bit like specifying some some specific `file.py` path, but instead abstractly among the named, findable, installed modules (whatever their filesystem paths might be). See: https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m

Comment: @gojomo That's interesting. The effect, a good one, has been to produce an error for any package I try to import that is not installed in the active env. Previously these packages were silently and invisibly to me being loaded from the base env. Using `python -m jupyter notebook` has had the happy result of forcing me to install these in the the env, making explicit which version is being called from where. Please write up your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @furas, my apologies. I did not understand your comment, having never seen or used `python -m` in the command to load jupyter, but it turned out to be the right one. Thanks for responding and sorry I didn't catch on sooner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per our discussion in the comments, when you launch via `jupyter` directly, it seems you're using some other (perhaps system-wide) Python interpreter & environment – one which doesn't have `gensim` installed – even though you've "activated" your `SARC` environment. (Essentially, "activating" an environment tries to alias `python` & some other things to use the right enviroment, but other commands might still reach out to some other Python installation.)

Per @furas' suggestion of using `python -m jupyter notebook`, you'll be sure to invoke plain `python`, and thus the `SARC` environment – and thus test whether `gensim` and/or `jupyter` are even really installed inside the `SARC` environment.

If not, be sure to install them there, and make sure any interpreters/notebooks you launch truly use the intended environment.